# Creating method using C# in ASP.NET with Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

**Problem resolved**: I found a reusable solution. Thank you everyone for your help.

I'm frustrated and don't know what I'm doing. I'm attempting to build a webpage and one of the things I'm trying to do is cut down on code. In order to do so, I need to create a method, I know extensively about methods from Java, but not when trying to write C# in ASP.NET using razor syntax. The problem I'm facing is my @helper refuses to access the global hash table "dictionary". I've tried a lot of different things and have decided to turn to stackoverflow for help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATES:

Error Message is "CS0103: The name 'dictionary' does not exist in the current context"

I need a hashtable because I'm pulling from a database, checking to see if its null, if yes, replacing it with an empty string, then pushing it to a table. So if I could learn how to do it in this fashion, it would work best, I think?

```
<!doctype html>

@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Linq;

@{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    dictionary.Add("fName", returnString100.FRSTNAME.Trim());

    @helper printOut(string toBePrinted) {
        object curValue;
        if(dictionary.TryGetValue(toBePrinted, out curValue)) { 
            return curValue; 
        }
    }
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td><td>@{ printOut("fName"); }</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sounds like this logic doesn't belong in your view or in a helper anyway. Why don't you declare your dictionary inside the helper method?

Comment: This looks like too much code for a view.  This should really belong in the model and the view would just reference a property of that model.

Comment: Please post the error that you get from this code.

Comment: Error message is "CS0103: The name 'dictionary' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1):

While philosophically I agree with the others that you might want to encapsulate this in a class, here's how you can do this in Razor with a view:

```
<!doctype html>

@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Linq;

@{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    dictionary.Add("fName", returnString100.FRSTNAME.Trim());

    Func<string, object> PrintOut = delegate(string toBePrinted)
    {
        object curValue;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(toBePrinted, out curValue))
            return curValue;
        return "";   
    };

}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td><td>@PrintOut("fName").ToString()</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: However I don't know where you're getting returnString100 from.  I'll leave that up to you, as that wasn't part of the question :)

Comment: Would it be possible to skip all this and just pull straight from my hash table. Example dictionary.TryGetValue("fName").ToString() ?

Comment: Also I don't see how the answer allows me to reuse the code as there isn't a parameter involved. I'm pulling a single name, as it is a per user display, so will need to use this for multiple fields